# IMG & DIV Resizing with JQuery leads images to resize without changing position relative to neighboring DIVs (They stay fixed and create overflow)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

It's almost doing what I want it to!

[Here's a JSFiddle of what I would like to accomplish](http://jsfiddle.net/dg3kj/480/). (Thanks to another user here, I found this while trying to find a solution for my problem. Move the middle vertical divider to the right to watch the image resize relative to the text).

[Here's a JSFiddle mockup of my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/y7d9nuLa/). (Move the middle divider to the left first to confirm that the images are side-by-side, then to the right to watch then resize accordingly. However, the images stay fixed to their position while resizing instead of dynamically staying side-by-side, and it create an overflow with a horizontal scrollbar).

You can view this live on my website for the full version, if needed at
 zsophianorris.info (click on the "photo" tab. Doesn't work on mobile).

**CODE SNIPPET**

```js
 var maxWidth  = $('.outer').width();
 var maxHeight = $('.outer').height();

 var windowWidth = $(window).width();
 var windowHeight = $(window).height();

 $(window).resize(function(evt) {
     var $window = $(window);
     var width = $window.width();
     var height = $window.height();
     var scale;

     // early exit
     if(width >= windowWidth && height >= windowHeight) {
         $('.outer').css({'-webkit-transform': ''});
         $('#fotowrapper').css({ width: '', height: '' });
         return;
     }

     //scale = Math.min(width/maxWidth, height/maxHeight);
     scale = Math.min(width/windowWidth, height/windowHeight);

     $('.outer').css({'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'});
     $('
```

```css
.fade {

}

.outer {
 float: left;
}

.fotoholder-top {
 position: relative;
 width: 480px;
 height: 320px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.fotoholder {
 position: relative;
 width: 480px;
 height: 320px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 font: 400 50px/1.3 'Oleo Script', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(17,17,17,0.3);
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 320px;
}

.fotoholder-top img, .fotoholder img, .overlay {
 transition: .3s all;
}

.fotoholder-top img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

.fotoholder img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

.fotoholder-top:hover .overlay {
 opacity: 1;
}

.fotoholder:hover .overlay {
 opacity: 1;
}

.fotoholder-top:hover img {
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.fotoholder:hover img {
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 transform: scale(1.1);
 -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fotowrpper">
  <div class="outer fade">
    <a href="http://zaralyyth.deviantart.com/art/Long-Night-of-Solace-564652691" target="_tab">
      <div class="fotoholder-top">
        <img class="foto" src="http://i.imgur.com/hA7jtkO.jpg">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2>Solace</h2>
        </div>
      </div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="outer fade">
    <a href="http://zaralyyth.deviantart.com/art/Recollection-682091553" target="_tab">
      <div class="fotoholder-top">
        <img class="foto" src="http://i.imgur.com/3W1QVDz.jpg">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2>Recollection</h2>
        </div>
      </div></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `fotoholder` rulesets have fixed widths of `480px`  Unless that changes when the images are scaled, your holders aren't going to shrink as the pictures do.